# Building a glm model with weights in dlply

Tags: r, plyr, glm

I wrote a script that for every Id i build a model. 
Data is a data.frame, that for every Id i have several rows that i can build for him a model. so dlply take this subset of data.frame for each Id and build for him a model.

```
model<- dlply(Data, "Id", 
               function(df) {
                 HistoryWeights<-1+log(length(df$Row))
                 model<-glm(formula = form,family = binomial("logit"),data = df,weights = HistoryWeights)
                 return(model)
                 })
```

The problem is that if i run the script without the `weights` all fine. But if i add the weights in glm model this return me:
**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'HistoryWeights' not found**

Here is a simple example with iris:

```
Data<-iris
Data$Predicted<- ceiling(rnorm(dim(Data)[1],0,0.00001))
Data$Row<-1:nrow(Data)
form<-formula(Predicted~Sepal.Length
              +Sepal.Width
              +Petal.Length
              +Petal.Width)
model<- dlply(Data, "Species", 
              function(df) {
                HistoryWeights<-1+log(length(df$Row))
                model<-glm(formula = form,family = binomial("logit"),data = df,weights = HistoryWeights)
                return(model)
              })
```

What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: The help page for `glm` gives " If not found in data, the variables are taken from environment(formula), typically the environment from which glm is called."  Note: it searches for HistoryWeights in the environment of the formula, *not* the calling environment of glm.

Comment: @kasterma So what should i do?

Comment: The answer @Spacedman gives works, the other is to define the function in the function so that your HistoryWeights is defined in the environment where the formula is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, put `HistoryWeights` as a column in the data frame:

```
model<- dlply(Data, "Species", 
              function(df) {
                df$HistoryWeights<-1+log(length(df$Row))
                model<-glm(formula = form,family = binomial("logit"),data = df,weights = HistoryWeights)
                return(model)
              })
```